# Entity Framework - how to select properties from two database class to another class

Tags: entity-framework, lambda

I Made a new notMapped class "BuyingHistory", that have some property (not all) of two database tables

how to fill this class with entity? I made the conditions, but how do I select the properties to a list? (I know how to do it for one property but not for a list)

```
         IQueryable<BuyingHistory> _buyingList = 
        _db.Orders
        .Join(_db.EventPages
        ,o => o.EventID
        ,e => e.ID
        ,(o, e) => new { orders = o, events = e })
        .Where(o => o.orders.UserID == LS.CurrentUser.ID)
        .Select( // I don't know how to continue
```

it's work in this way bellow, but how can I do it in one command like the example above

```
 var _List =
        _db.Orders
        .Join(_db.EventPages
        , o => o.EventID
        , e => e.ID
        , (o, e) => new { orders = o, events = e })
        .Where(o => o.orders.UserID == LS.CurrentUser.ID).ToList();

List<BuyingHistory> _buyingList = new List<BuyingHistory>();
 foreach (var item in _List)
{
    _buyingList.Add(new BuyingHistory()
    {
        CreatedDate = item.orders.CreatedDate,
        EventName = item.events.Title,
        NumberOfTickets = item.orders.TicketNumber,
        OrderID = item.orders.ID,
        Status = item.orders.Status.ToString(),
        Total = item.orders.TicketNumber
    });
}
```

Answer (score 1):

I'd use query syntax to begin with, and then do the query like so:

```
from ord in _db.Orders
join evt in _db.EventPages on ord.EventID equals evt.ID
where ord.UserID == LS.CurrentUser.ID
select new BuyingHistory
{
    CreatedDate = ord.CreatedDate,
    EventName = evt.Title,
    NumberOfTickets = ord.TicketNumber,
    OrderID = ord.ID,
    Status = ord.Status.ToString(),
    Total = ord.TicketNumber
})
```

If you have EF version 6 the `ToString()` won't throw exceptions. If not, you have to change the type  of `BuyingHistory.Status` into the type coming from the database.